# Calculating area of intersection of polygon to another layer in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, intersection, voronoi-thiessen

I am very new to GIS, especially ArcGIS.

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.2, and I have 2 layer, namely the purple feature map(this layer is an import from arcgis online, it doesn't seems to be an feature map) and voronoi diagram layer.

I am currently doing a project which requires me to find the intersection area of the purple map and each slices of voronoi polygon (for example, the highlighted polygon in the sample image) respectively.

I will expect answer like(if it is possible):
Polygon 0: 120km^2 
Polygon 1: 80km^2
Polygon 2: 20km^2
.....

Since there is only 9 polygon slice, I don't expect it to require python scripting. I hope someone can point me to the correct toolbox/feature to achieve the objective required.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about those tiny dark purple polygons? Is it a feature class stored in a geodatabase (or a shapefile) or just a basemap you consume from ArcGIS Online? If it is a feature class (i.e., you have it stored on your disk with coordinates), then you can use the Intersect GP tool to get a new output polygon with the areas common to both layers. After that you can just do the summary of all features that are intersecting each of the polygon (this information will be available in the attribute table).

Comment: i think it is not a feature class stored in geodatabase. The link of the purple polygon can be reach from http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8f35f9f25e0a450492bf72039aa781a6

Comment: Alright. Well, this is a tiled layer (think raster images), so you cannot just take them into a geoprocessing analysis. You should try to contact data author and see if you can get the raw data (vector) from them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will contact the data author now. However, I am still interested in finding any method in harvesting geodata from this type of raster image, or any method to do a reverse engineering back to shapefile?

Comment: When you have a raster image, you can digitize it manually by drawing new features on top of them. This is a time-consuming operation though. You can take a screenshot of the image and then use raster processing techniques for obtaining the shapes of raster parts.